# How to implement job/queue system with Sails JS

Tags: sails.js

Having background workers is a pretty common requirement for a decent sized app - but there doesn't seem to be any way to do this out of the box in Sails JS. What's the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the BEST way to do it, but this is how I have implemented it in our current system.

We're using sails.js in Elastic Beanstalk on AWS. This allows me to deploy a worker environment which listens to a queue. The configuration requires an endpoint which receives the messages from the queue.

With this in mind, I have created a `WorkerController` which has only an `index` action. This index action behaves as a router for the functions required to be executed via the queue.

You will need to lock down this controller+action route for security purposes.

To trigger the worker, I send a message to the queue with JSON body containing the parameters required. An example message would be:

```
{
    "task": "processTransaction",
    "id": 1207
}
```

These parameters are available to the `WorkerController.index` action as request parameters, which are then used to trigger a function and pass the arguments.